# Как через easygui ввести текст?

Tags: python

Как через easygui ввести текст? Например, ввести цифры можно вот так:

```
easygui.integerbox(
msg = "Введите число от 1 до 10",
title = "Stackoverflow",
lowerbound = 1111111,
upperbound = 9999999)
```

А как тогда ввести текст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Пример из документации](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html#letting-the-user-enter-information):

```
from easygui import multenterbox

msg = "Enter your personal information"
title = "Credit Card Application"
fieldNames = ["Name", "Street Address", "City", "State", "ZipCode"]
fieldValues = multenterbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а это для какой версии python? Я попробовал на python 3 запустить и у меня вылезла ошибка - msg = "Enter your personal information"
title = "Credit Card Application"
fieldNames = ["Name", "Street Address", "City", "State", "ZipCode"]
fieldValues = multenterbox(msg, title, fieldNames)

Comment: @OMEGA какая ошибка?

Comment: не то скопировал, сейчас

Comment: name 'multenterbox' is not defined

Comment: @OMEGA так вы импортировали это имя из библиотеки? `from easygui import multenterbox`

Comment: @OMEGA обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь все получилось

Comment: Я импортировал так - import easygui

Comment: скажите, а как сделать так, чтобы если я написал fieldNames = "Name" - Name выводилось как 1 пункт, а не 
N
a
m
e (как 4 пункта)

Comment: @OMEGA лучше задайте новый вопрос с картинкой, что не так отображается. Непонятно пока, в чём проблема

Comment: я поправил вопрос.

Comment: @OMEGA подождите, у вас изначально совсем другой вопрос был. Откатите на предыдущую версию и задайте новый. Сейчас проблема в том, что `fieldNames` должен быть списком, а вы передаёте строку, поэтому она разбивается в список посимвольно `['N', 'a', 'm', 'e']`. Используйте `["Name"]`, а лучше `enterbox`, если вам нужна только одна строка.

Comment: спасибо большое!!!